# Can't I send an array in params with JSONHTTPClient?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, jsonhttpclient

I'm trying send some params: a NSString and an NSarray.

The `NSArray` have this format when I print this:

```
(54,

55)
```

But when I add this to params into JSONHTTPClient I get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request parameters can be
>   only of NSString or NSNumber classes.

My code is:

```
[JSONHTTPClient postJSONFromURLWithString:uploadUrl 
 params:@{@"idKey":@"689769", @"idFree":myArray}
                               completion:^(NSDictionary *json, JSONModelError *err)

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

 NSLog(@"complet");
 });
}];
```

How can I send an array into params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the library doesn't support it, then you probably have to serialise it yourself. You can use the NSJSONSerialization Class for that:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/dataWithJSONObject:options:error:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myArray options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now you have myString instead of myArray so it should be happy!